# Online Payment with Android Apps

Tags: android, webview

I have to write an online-payment android apps.
The apps has a timer, the page will be expired when time's up.

My apps will link to payment gateway webpage via WebView, user will have to login to banker website, confirm the amount, and press the CONFIRM button.

The timer should be stopped when my apps receives the payment status from the payment gateway.

The question is, I am not pretty sure what are the functions can be utilized in android programming to trace there is the result from payment gateway.

Appreciate if there is any suggestions or hints.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, how did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

try to work with paypal integration.. i have attached the link gothrough..

http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/04/adding-paypal-payment-in-android.html

Comment: Hi Janmejoy, thank you for your reply. I've read thru your code, it seems the apps creates the form to communicate directly to paypal. Unfortunately my case is different. I will be using WEBVIEW to connect to the banker https url. Then the bank login form, confirm to pay buttons are actually located at server side, not controlled by apps..